# Django based app on heroku showing error HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: heroku, arduino, django-rest-framework, gsm, arduino-due

I need to send some data from an arduino to an rest based web application.

To test I have created an django based web application on heroku

Now when I trying to send the data from arduino using GSM AT commands it's showing below error

`HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Connection: close
Server: Cowboy`

Below is my code in arduino

```
  const char HTTP_HEADER_POST[ ] = "POST /api/sprints  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: obttracker.herokuapp.com\r\nContent-Length: 54\r\n\r\nUser-Agent: obttracker\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/x-wwww-form-urlencoded\r\nAuthorization: Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v\r\n\r\n";  //HTTP header line before length 
  const char HTTP_BODY_POST[] = "end=2015-05-19&name=TESTING&point=POINT%2834.2+45.3%29";

   int tmp_post_len = strlen(HTTP_HEADER_POST);  
   //sending header packet to remote host
   gsm_port.print("AT+QISEND=");
   gsm_port.print(tmp_post_len); 
   gsm_port.print("\r");

   delay(500);
   gsm_get_reply();

   //sending header                     
   gsm_port.print(HTTP_HEADER_POST);

   delay(500);
   gsm_get_reply();

   //validate header delivery
   gsm_validate_tcp();

   // send the body data
   int body_len = strlen(HTTP_BODY_POST);
   gsm_port.print("AT+QISEND=");
   gsm_port.print(body_len); 
   gsm_port.print("\r");

   delay(500);
   gsm_get_reply();  

   gsm_port.print(HTTP_BODY_POST);

   delay(500);
   gsm_get_reply(); 

   //validate previous transmission  
   gsm_validate_tcp();

   parse_receive_reply();
```

I have tested the web app by send through my linux system using python requests, and it's working below are the details

```
   $ python
   Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
   [GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> import datetime
   >>> import requests
   >>> import pprint
   >>> today = datetime.date.today()
   >>> data = {'name': 'TESTSTING', 'end': today, 'point': 'POINT(56.3        33.3)'}
   >>> resp = requests.get('http://obttracker.herokuapp.com/api')
   >>> resp.status_code
   200
   >>> api = resp.json()
   >>> pprint.pprint(api)
   {u'sprints': u'http://obttracker.herokuapp.com/api/sprints'}
   >>> resp = requests.post(api['sprints'], data=data, auth=('demo', 'demo'))
   >>> resp.status_code
   201
   >>> sprint = resp.json()
   >>> pprint.pprint(sprint)
   {u'end': u'2015-04-24',
    u'id': 3,
    u'links': {u'self':     u'http://obttracker.herokuapp.com/api/sprints/3'},
    u'name': u'TESTSTING',
    u'point': {u'coordinates': [56.3, 33.3], u'type': u'Point'}}
   >>>
```

Request to please provide me suggestion or help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Got it resolved, The issue is with the encoding of "Content-Length" in HTTP Header. It need to converted to ASCII. Also the typo error of double space in "/api/sprints  HTTP/1.1\r\n" will lead to the same issue. :)

I am stupid doing silly error, after 19 hours of continuous coding.